# How could I list all objects under a prefix in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

There are more than 3k objects under the prefix. I use the following code to list all objects to get their names, but the API only retrieve 1000 objects.
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

```
response = s3_client.list_objects(
    Bucket = "my-bucket",
    Prefix = "my-prefix",
    MaxKeys=50000
)


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3)

print(len(response['Contents'])) # only retrieve 1000
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use paginators to loop through multiple pages. See: [Creating Paginators](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
operation_parameters = {'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
                        'Prefix': 'my-prefix'}
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)
for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Contents'])
```